# Opencart seo Url rewriting duplicate names

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo, opencart

I'm playing with the seo functionality within Opencart. It all works fine except for one case.

In my menu I have a few submenus like below

```
- Tire Retreading
    - Rounding
        - Agricultural
    - Equalizing
- Tires
    - Michelin
        - Agricultural
```

Now SEO url rewriting should give me a few urls:

```
http://domain.com/
http://domain.com/Tire-Retreading/
http://domain.com/Tire-Retreading/Rounding/
http://domain.com/Tire-Retreading/Rounding/Agricultural/
http://domain.com/Tire-Retreading/Equalizing/
http://domain.com/Tires/
http://domain.com/Tires/Michelin/
http://domain.com/Tires/Michelin/Agricultral/
```

Every url seems to work except for these two:

```
http://domain.com/Tires-Retreading/Rounding/Agricultural/
http://domain.com/Tires/Michelin/Agricultral/
```

The result is this one of the two urls becomes the other.

Now I was wondering why and how to get this to work so both pages end up to the correct link. The underlying links are:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=25_65_72
http://domain.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=36_70_67
```

The value of path seperated by the _ is the respectively category_id known in the database.

My .htacces file:

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It's the default opencart one.
I'm using OpenCart v2.0.1.0

Comment: Can you paste the relevant parts of the htaccess file here instead of just linking to pastebin?

Comment: Added the .htaccess file